# Создаю файл, передаю в модель и получаю неожиданную ошибку

Tags: python, django

Создал модель БД в которую хочу складывать файл о проведенном тестировании и список проведенных тестов в виде строки.

Models.py

```
class ReportClass(models.Model):
    report = models.FileField()
    ran_tests = models.CharField('Проведенные тесты', max_length=1000, default='')
    date = models.DateField('Дата проведения', default=datetime.date.today)
```

В функции создаю файл в который кладу некоторый отчет

```
report_file = open('report.txt', 'w')
```

Потом формирую строку str, в которой указаны наименование проведенных тестов

```
running_tests = ''
...
running_tests = running_tests + TestClass.objects.get(pk=int(s_id)).name + ', '
```

(UPD) TestClass.objects.get().name тоже CharField

```
class TestClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Название', max_length=50, default='')
```

Потом пытаюсь создать объект класса Report class

```
report = ReportClass.objects.create(report=report_file, ran_tests=running_tests)
```

и получаю ошибку:
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute '_committed'

Прошу вразумить и ткнуть носом, где я накосячил...

Comment: `report = models.FileField()` - тут явно не ожидается просто открытый файл питона `report=report_file`, а что-то другое

Comment: Думал об этом... Перед create пробовал делать report_file.close(),  но результат тот же...

Comment: На сколько я понимаю есть какая магия вуду между созданием файла и загрузкой его через форму... На сколько я понял документацию FileField ориентировано именно на загружаемые файлы. При этом как в БД класть то, что программа генерит сама я пока так и не понял...

Comment: Ну там в доке что-то есть на тему типа `File` самого `Django` и что-то ещё там. Почитайте. Я не спец, но что-то там можно явно накопать. `FileField` да, это похоже для загрузки через форму только.

Comment: Кажется нащупал... В django хранятся не файлы, а ссылки на файл... попробовал передать report_file.name. Ругаться перестал... Проверяю...

Answer (score 1):

Так как в django хранятся не файлы, а ссылки на файл то необходимо передавать путь к файлу. Например так

```
...create(report=report_file.name, ran_tests=running_tests)
```